# Elsevier class : Abstract without top and bottom lines

Tags: elsarticle

I am using `\documentclass[5p]{elsarticle}` to write a paper, but I do not want to include horizontal lines to write Abstract. Can some one guide me?

```
\documentclass[5p]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{lineno,hyperref}
\modulolinenumbers[5]

\journal{Journal of \LaTeX\ Templates}


\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}

\title{test title}

\author{ Hariha\corref{cor1}*}


\address{820081,Fukuoka, Japan}
%\fntext[myfootnote]{Since 1880.}
\cortext[mycorrespondingauthor]{Corresponding author}
\ead{me@lab.jp}

\begin{abstract}
This template helps you to create a properly formatted \LaTeX\ manuscript.
\end{abstract}

\begin{keyword}
MEMS
%\texttt{elsarticle.cls}\sep \LaTeX\sep Elsevier \sep template
%\MSC[2010] 00-01\sep  99-00
\end{keyword}

\end{frontmatter}

%\linenumbers
\section{The Elsevier article class}

\paragraph{Installation} If the document class \emph{elsarticle} is not available on your computer, you can download and install the system package \emph{texlive-publishers} (Linux) or install the \LaTeX\ package \emph{elsarticle} using the package manager of your \TeX\ installation, which is typically \TeX\ Live or Mik\TeX.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you please add a [minimal but working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem and that can be used to reproduce the problem and to test our suggestions. This would help us to help you.

Comment: Off-Topic: Do you want to publish the article at Elsevier? Are you sure that the publish agrees with such changes? Authors often try to change settings and results of publisher classes, the afterwards will be thrown away by the editor.

Comment: I do not want to publish in Elsevier. I am writing for some conference which has the same format without those lines in Abstract @Schweinebacke

Comment: Please have a look at our [Help Center](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help) so see how we use markdown for the formatting. You can get a link to the markdown help also by clicking to the question mark at the right side of the toolbar of the editor field.

Comment: @Schweinebacke I m sorry. I could not able to get the suggested link at Help Center

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/search?q=markdown. The other link can be found if you click to the question mark at the toolbar of the editor field if you edit your question or the editor field for answers.

Comment: @Schweinebacke Is something wrong with my post. I mean you can not able to see my code.

Comment: As you can see below the question, I've edited it to fix the formatting. I've done so with the original question and again after you've added the example. After fixing the formatting, I've added the comment to let you know how you can do it on your own next time. That's all.

Comment: @Schweinebacke: Thank you. I will follow it.  Could you suggest something to remove those two lines in the abstract. Thank you again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case `\MaketitleBox` is use to make the title. There are two `\hrule` commands in the definition of `\MaketitleBox` to make the horizontal rule aboce the abstract and below the keywords. You can use package `xpatch` to remove these `\hrule`s from the definition of `\MaketitleBox`:

```
\documentclass[5p]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd{\MaketitleBox}{\hrule}{}{}{}% remove first horizontal rule (above abstract)
\xpatchcmd{\MaketitleBox}{\hrule}{}{}{}% remoce second horizonral rule (below keywords)

\usepackage{lineno,hyperref}
\modulolinenumbers[5]

\journal{Journal of \LaTeX\ Templates}


\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}

\title{test title}

\author{ Hariha\corref{cor1}*}


\address{820081,Fukuoka, Japan}
%\fntext[myfootnote]{Since 1880.}
\cortext[mycorrespondingauthor]{Corresponding author}
\ead{me@lab.jp}

\begin{abstract}
This template helps you to create a properly formatted \LaTeX\ manuscript.
\end{abstract}

\begin{keyword}
MEMS
%\texttt{elsarticle.cls}\sep \LaTeX\sep Elsevier \sep template
%\MSC[2010] 00-01\sep  99-00
\end{keyword}

\end{frontmatter}

%\linenumbers
\section{The Elsevier article class}

\paragraph{Installation} If the document class \emph{elsarticle} is not available on your computer, you can download and install the system package \emph{texlive-publishers} (Linux) or install the \LaTeX\ package \emph{elsarticle} using the package manager of your \TeX\ installation, which is typically \TeX\ Live or Mik\TeX.

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you only want to remove the rule above the abstract use only one `\xpatchcmd`.

Note: With option `preprint` instead of `5p` `elsarticle` would use `\pprintMaketitle` instead of `\MaketitleBox`. In this case the patches would be the same but with `\pprintMaketitle` instead of `\MaketitleBox`:

```
\xpatchcmd{\pprintMaketitle}{\hrule}{}{}{}% remove first horizontal rule
\xpatchcmd{\pprintMaketitle}{\hrule}{}{}{}% remoce second horizonral rule
```

You can use both to have a solution that is independent from the options.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is what I was looking. You saved my time. Thank you very much for your kind support.

Comment: @Prakash: Please consider to cast a vote or even to accept an answer if you find an answer helpful. See [The Tour](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tour) for information about how to vote and accept answers.

Comment: How to cast vote?

Comment: @Prakash Please have a look at the tour. There you can find: "Good answers are voted up and rise to the top." The shown symbol to click to is left beside the top of every question and answer. If you have not yet voted it is hollow. After voting it is filled like shown in the tour.